# No Module named <module_name> but i have the module correctly linked

Tags: python, django

My actual folder structure is the next one

```
>django_app/
  >django_models/
    >Model_1
  >django_views/
    >View_1
  >models.py
  >views.py
```

Inside 'models.py' i have this:
`from django_app.django_models.Model_1 import Model_1(This is the class name)`

but when i try to run server i get this error:

```
   from django_app.django_models.Model_1 import Model_1
ImportError: No module named django_models.Model_1
```

i have done this before in django 3.2 and restframework, but rn isn't working as expected
*Python == 2.7
*Django == 1.6.5

this is an old project from my company and we dont have time to uptade it to newer versions.

Comment: Did you also try `from django_models.Model_1 import Model_1` ?

Comment: Yes it didnt work, also tried ```from django_models.Model_1 import Model_1 ``` and didnt work either

Comment: Is `Model_1` a directory or is it `Model_1.py` ?

Comment: Model_1 is a py

Comment: Also tried this```from django_app.django_models import Model_1```, didnt work
its like its not founding the django_models directory

Comment: Try to put an empty file named `__init__.py`  into the dir `django_models`

Comment: It Worked!! Thanks!

Comment: Please mark the correct answer so others will be pointed to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was adding an empty file named `__init__.py` into the dir django_models